# Do Barbarians in Pathfinder lose any class abilities if they become lawful?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, multi-classing, alignment, barbarian

Looking to make a starting level 6 multiclass character with barbarian/monk/druid levels. First two levels are barbarian, then the others.

I know paladins lose paladin-stuff if they slip from lawful good. Is their anything that barbarians lose if they become lawful later in life?

Comment: while this has been effectively answered i think its worth noting 2 things
A. while the barb loses the ability to rage when monks slip out of lawful the only thing they lose is access to more monk levels
B. Barbs are only required to be non-lawful so the Aasimar race trait, Enlightened Warrior, would allow you to take both while maintaining a N or NG alignment. This can be taken by any race by taking the Adopted trait

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/#TOC-Mighty-Rage-Ex-) (under the 20th level ability Mighty Rage)

> Ex-Barbarians
>
> A barbarian who becomes lawful **loses the ability to rage and cannot gain more levels as a barbarian.** She retains all other benefits of the class.

Unchained Barbarian conspicuously does not have this line. It's unclear whether that's oversight or intentional, and likely up to the GM whether it applies or not.